# How to get root privilege in recovery mode?

Tags: rooting, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging

I have copyed the 'su' command to /system in adb. but i cannot run the 'su', 'su' says: Permission denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what device you are using, but [z4root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=872344) will allow you to root Droid X (as well as Droid I believe).  It should provide temporary and permanent root access.  **As always, you use this at your own risk.**

Answer (score 1):

Install the Superuser app from the Market and reboot.  Then try running su from adb with your device connected to your computer -- Superuser should pop up a notification on the phone asking if you want to allow it to run.  Then you can use it.  Note your phone must be rooted.